# Antlr cpp runtime Any bad cast of pointer?

Tags: c++, antlr, covariance

I get following error using antlr cpp runtime. 
pseudo-code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <antlr4-common.h>

#include <antlr4-runtime.h>

using namespace antlrcpp;
using namespace antlr4;
using namespace std;

class B{
public:
    virtual void myhello() = 0;
};

class A:public B{
public:
    string name;
    A (string a):name(a){
    }

    virtual void myhello(){
        cout << "hello "<< name <<endl;
    }
};

Any f1(){
  A *a = new A("hello");
  return Any(a);
}

Any f2(){
  B* v= f1().as<B*>();
  return Any(v);
}


int main(){
    auto x = f2();
    x.as<A*>()->myhello();
    return 0;
}
```

Error: bad_cast of line `B* v= f1().as<B*>()`;

However when I wrote `B* b= new A();` in `f1`, it becomes OK.

I guess it is related to *covariance*.

an `A*` instance can always be casted to `B*` since `B` is the base of `A`.

However `Any<A*>` in antlr-runtime cannot be `as <B*>()`.

Comment: You need a [mcve], your question is off-topic without it.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I have provided enough code, please remove -1 and reopen the question.

Comment: @machine_1 I have provided enough code, please remove -1 and reopen the question.

Comment: Can you please also provide the verbatim error message you get from compiling that code? And yes, I'm already voting to reopen this with the given code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast the result of `f2()` to `A*` because `A` derives from `B` and you only created an instance of `B`. How can that become a valid `A` instance? Did you perhaps mean to reverse the names, by making `A` the base class and `B` the one that derives?

Comment: In f2, I make it to B*, in the content of Any returned from f1, it stores a pointer of A*. But A* can be considerred as B* as any time.

Comment: Oh, right. I missed that. Then I think it's a problem of [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). The Any object you return from `f2()` no longer contains an instance of `A`. It has been sliced off by `B* v= f1().as<B*>();`.

Comment: umm, but I am passing a pointer to Any, the pointers are always the same size I guess. Does Any deal with pointer specially?